# Using input to call a member function

Tags: c++, function, member, cin

Is it possible to use Input to call a member function?

```
void one()
{
}

cout << "enter input:" << endl;
cin >> input;  //where input is "one"

instance.input()
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit? Do you want to call a function given its name as input?

Comment: It's possible, but it's not a beginner task. You either have to make a list/table of functions and names, or hack the language to produce such a list for you. You might want to try a language besides C++.

Answer (score 2):

If all of your methods have the same number of arguments (or preferably, no arguments), then you can easily do this using an std::map.

Use the method name as key of the map, use a pointer to the method as value in the map.
Then lookup the entered string in the map, and execute its corresponding method via the method pointer.

Be careful with non-static methods.  Function pointers and pointers to static methods are quite easy, but non-static method pointers are a bit more difficult.  See http://www.goingware.com/tips/member-pointers.html for more information.

Comment: I think you might be able to do with with varying numbers of parameters using boost::bind and boost::function too.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't - because `input` is not an [lvalue](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp7l.doc/language/ref/clrc05lvalue.htm).

Comment: Then is there anyway to get that accomplished? Else I'm going to have to use a ton of IF statements.  If (input == "one") then.... yada yada.

Comment: You should accept Patricks answer if it is good for you (done using the hook on the left of the answer).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for the [Interpreter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern) and the [Command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) pattern.